# How to write code for GUI designed in independent Qt designer using Qt creator?

Tags: qt, user-interface, integration

I have a manjaro Linux system. It comes preinstalled with a Qt designer software that has more widgets compared to default Qt creator. But I can only design GUI with this designer software. How would I write code for it?

I have Qt Creator 5.5 installed, but I don't know if it it possible to integrate these two and if yes, how?

Comment: Qt designer simply allows convenient editing of .ui files, which are later compiled through a QtCreator (for example, may also be compiled from command line). Just make sure that your compiler has access to the special widgets libraries, otherwise there should be no problems.

Comment: @Anorflame How to make those widget libraries available to Qtcreator?